# Any other ways to hedge a bond portfolio against interest rate risk?

Tags: fixed-income, interest-rates, derivatives, hedging

I'm currently taking a (gentle) intro to derivatives class. One of the exercises asked me to discuss duration as a risk measure and to provide alternative methods of hedging a bond portfolio against interest rate risks (other than using bond futures). While I managed to answer the first part, I'm wondering: what other methods could there be? I did some googling and stumbled upon other interest rate derivatives such as swaps and interest rate options but unfortunately none of them really include a proper explanation of how such a hedge would work so I'm a bit stuck right now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are long a bond and want to hedge it:

1. Sell the same bond.
2. Sell another bond.
3. Sell a bond future.
4. Pay a swap.
5. Buy a payer swaption.

Those are some basic methods. Ofcourse there are many nuances with each of the methods prescribed above. But the question is quite vague, so a vague answer should suffice.

Comment: I think the OP wants to hedge away the ensitivity to the credit risk free interest rate, while still earning the credit spread. Selling the same bond won't quite do it, but selling a treasury or a lower yielding bond might.